# How do I use a python variable in a SQLITE SELECT statement

Tags: python, variables, sqlite

So i was trying to use a local varibale made in python to be used in my SQL statement but I get the error sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "1AM"

```
    if schchoice==int("1"):
                            schchoice=str("12AM")
                    elif schchoice == int("2"):
                            schchoice="1AM"
                    else:
                        print("INVALID")


                    if schchoice2==int("1"):
                        schchoice=str("12AM")
                    elif schchoice2==int("2"):
                        schchoice2="1AM"
                    else:
                            print("INVALID")
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('Employee.db')
                    c = conn.cursor()
                    def read_from_db():
                                c.execute("SELECT FName,LName, monstarthour, monendhour FROM MondayHours WHERE monstarthour ='"+schchoice+"'AND monendhour='"+schchoice2+'"')
                                #data = c.fetchall()
                                for row in c.fetchall():
                                    print(row)
                    read_from_db()
```

Comment: The formatting here is broken....  Please fix.

Comment: Don't concatenate string variables with query strings. You're liable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Use ```string.format()``` instead: ```c.execute("SELECT FName,LName, monstarthour, monendhour FROM MondayHours WHERE monstarthour='{}' AND monendhour='{}'".format(schoice, schoice2))```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should never use string manipulation to insert variable values into your SQL query, or else you are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The safe way to achieve what you are trying to do is to pass in values as parameters to your SQL engine, which will do all of the necessary escaping for you. In your case, something like this should work:

```
params = (schchoice, schchoice2)
c.execute("SELECT FName,LName, monstarthour, monendhour FROM MondayHours WHERE monstarthour = ? AND monendhour = ?", params)
```